# online azure table is working but offline is not

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services

I am trying offline sync in my azure mobile app but it always returns null pointer.I been debugging to reach the root of error for 3 days but cannot figure it out.Any help will be highly appreciated.Every time i debug i get this error,I have followed the same steps provided by Microsoft azre.

My class is

```
  public class User {

@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
private String mId;
@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("phonenumber")
private String mText;


@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("email")
private boolean mComplete;
@com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("name")
private String mName;

public User() {

}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return getText();
}


public User(String text, String id) {
    this.setText(text);
    this.setId(id);
}


public String getText() {
    return mText;
}


public final void setText(String text) {
    mText = text;
}


public String getId() {
    return mId;
}


public final void setId(String id) {
    mId = id;
}


public boolean isComplete() {
    return mComplete;
}

public void setComplete(boolean complete) {
    mComplete = complete;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return o instanceof User && ((User) o).mId == mId;
}}
```

and my activity is

public class ToDoActivity extends Activity {

```
/**
 * Mobile Service Client reference
 */
private MobileServiceClient mClient;



//Offline Sync
/**
 * Mobile Service Table used to access and Sync data
 */
private MobileServiceSyncTable<User> mToDoTable;

/**
 * Adapter to sync the items list with the view
 */
private ToDoItemAdapter mAdapter;

/**
 * EditText containing the "New To Do" text
 */
private EditText mTextNewToDo;

/**
 * Progress spinner to use for table operations
 */
private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

/**
 * Initializes the activity
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do);

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingProgressBar);

    // Initialize the progress bar
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);

    try {
        // Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided

        // Mobile Service URL and key
        mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                "https://housewrench.azurewebsites.net",
                this).withFilter(new ProgressFilter());

        // Extend timeout from default of 10s to 20s
        mClient.setAndroidHttpClientFactory(new OkHttpClientFactory() {
            @Override
            public OkHttpClient createOkHttpClient() {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                client.setReadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                client.setWriteTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                return client;
            }
        });

        // Get the Mobile Service Table instance to use

       // mToDoTable = mClient.getTable(ToDoItem.class);
       // mUserTable = mClient.getTable(User.class);

        // Offline Sync
       mToDoTable = mClient.getSyncTable("User", User.class);

        //Init local storage
        initLocalStore().get();

        mTextNewToDo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textNewToDo);

        // Create an adapter to bind the items with the view
        mAdapter = new ToDoItemAdapter(this, R.layout.row_list_to_do);
        ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewToDo);
        listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Load the items from the Mobile Service
        refreshItemsFromTable();

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        createAndShowDialog(new Exception("There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL"), "Error");
    } catch (Exception e){
        createAndShowDialog(e, "Error");
    }
}

/**
 * Initializes the activity menu
 */
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

/**
 * Select an option from the menu
 */
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.menu_refresh) {
        refreshItemsFromTable();
    }

    return true;
}

/**
 * Mark an item as completed
 *
 * @param item
 *            The item to mark
 */
public void checkItem(final ToDoItem item) {
    if (mClient == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Set the item as completed and update it in the table
    item.setComplete(true);

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                checkItemInTable(item);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (item.isComplete()) {
                            mAdapter.remove(item);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");
            }

            return null;
        }
    };

    runAsyncTask(task);

}

/**
 * Mark an item as completed in the Mobile Service Table
 *
 * @param item
 *            The item to mark
 */
public void checkItemInTable(ToDoItem item) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    //mToDoTable.update(item).get();
}

/**
 * Add a new item
 *
 * @param view
 *            The view that originated the call
 */
public void addItem(View view) {
    if (mClient == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Create a new item
    final ToDoItem item = new ToDoItem();

    item.setText(mTextNewToDo.getText().toString());
    item.setComplete(false);

    // Insert the new item
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                final ToDoItem entity = addItemInTable(item);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if(!entity.isComplete()){
                            mAdapter.add(entity);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    runAsyncTask(task);

    mTextNewToDo.setText("");
}

/**
 * Add an item to the Mobile Service Table
 *
 * @param item
 *            The item to Add
 */
public ToDoItem addItemInTable(ToDoItem item) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
   // ToDoItem entity = mToDoTable.insert(item).get();
    return item;
}

/**
 * Refresh the list with the items in the Table
 */
    private void refreshItemsFromTable() {

    // Get the items that weren't marked as completed and add them in the
    // adapter

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                //final List<User> results = refreshItemsFromMobileServiceTable();

                //Offline Sync
                final List<User> results = refreshItemsFromMobileServiceTableSyncTable();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mAdapter.clear();

                        for (User item : results) {
                            //mAdapter.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (final Exception e){
                createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");
            }

            return null;
        }
    };

    runAsyncTask(task);
}

/**
 * Refresh the list with the items in the Mobile Service Table
 */

        private List<User> refreshItemsFromMobileServiceTable() throws 
       ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    return mUserTable.where().field("name").
            eq(val("noor")).execute().get();
}

//Offline Sync
/**
 * Refresh the list with the items in the Mobile Service Sync Table
 */
   private List<User> refreshItemsFromMobileServiceTableSyncTable() throws 
  ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    //sync the data
    sync().get();
    Query query = QueryOperations.field("phonenumber").
            eq(val(false));
    return mToDoTable.read(query).get();
}

/**
 * Initialize local storage
 * @return
 * @throws MobileServiceLocalStoreException
 * @throws ExecutionException
 * @throws InterruptedException
 */
private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> initLocalStore() throws MobileServiceLocalStoreException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                MobileServiceSyncContext syncContext = mClient.getSyncContext();

                if (syncContext.isInitialized())
                    return null;

                SQLiteLocalStore localStore = new SQLiteLocalStore(mClient.getContext(), "MyStore", null, 1);

                Map<String, ColumnDataType> tableDefinition = new HashMap<String, ColumnDataType>();
                tableDefinition.put("id", ColumnDataType.String);
                tableDefinition.put("phonenumber", ColumnDataType.String);
                tableDefinition.put("name", ColumnDataType.String);
                tableDefinition.put("email", ColumnDataType.String);

                localStore.defineTable("User", tableDefinition);

                SimpleSyncHandler handler = new SimpleSyncHandler();

                syncContext.initialize(localStore, handler).get();

            } catch (final Exception e) {
                createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");
            }

            return null;
        }
    };

    return runAsyncTask(task);
}

//Offline Sync
/**
 * Sync the current context and the Mobile Service Sync Table
 * @return
 */

private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> sync() {
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>(){
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                MobileServiceSyncContext syncContext = mClient.getSyncContext();
                syncContext.push().get();
                mToDoTable.pull(null).get();
            } catch (final Exception e) {
                createAndShowDialogFromTask(e, "Error");
            }
            return null;
        }
    };
    return runAsyncTask(task);
}


/**
 * Creates a dialog and shows it
 *
 * @param exception
 *            The exception to show in the dialog
 * @param title
 *            The dialog title
 */
private void createAndShowDialogFromTask(final Exception exception, String title) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            createAndShowDialog(exception, "Error");
        }
    });
}


/**
 * Creates a dialog and shows it
 *
 * @param exception
 *            The exception to show in the dialog
 * @param title
 *            The dialog title
 */
private void createAndShowDialog(Exception exception, String title) {
    Throwable ex = exception;
    if(exception.getCause() != null){
        ex = exception.getCause();
    }
    createAndShowDialog(ex.getMessage(), title);
}

/**
 * Creates a dialog and shows it
 *
 * @param message
 *            The dialog message
 * @param title
 *            The dialog title
 */
private void createAndShowDialog(final String message, final String title) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder.setMessage(message);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.create().show();
}

/**
 * Run an ASync task on the corresponding executor
 * @param task
 * @return
 */
private AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> runAsyncTask(AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> task) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        return task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
    } else {
        return task.execute();
    }
}

private class ProgressFilter implements ServiceFilter {

    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<ServiceFilterResponse> handleRequest(ServiceFilterRequest request, NextServiceFilterCallback nextServiceFilterCallback) {

        final SettableFuture<ServiceFilterResponse> resultFuture = SettableFuture.create();


        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mProgressBar != null) mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            }
        });

        ListenableFuture<ServiceFilterResponse> future = nextServiceFilterCallback.onNext(request);

        Futures.addCallback(future, new FutureCallback<ServiceFilterResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable e) {
                resultFuture.setException(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (mProgressBar != null) mProgressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
                    }
                });

                resultFuture.set(response);
            }
        });

        return resultFuture;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, it seems that you have followed the [Azure mobile apps quickstart sample for android](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-quickstarts/tree/master/client/android) and adjusted the `ToDoItem` to your `User`. I noticed that you did not set properly getter and setter for your `name` column, and the definition for your `email` column is String, but your assigned it to the boolean mComplete.

I would recommend you check the offline sync against your `ToDoItem` table is correctly. And you'd better set breakpoints to the `catch` code block to see which task throws the exception and check the relevant code to narrow this issue. If you could not solve this issue, you could update your question with the specific code line(s) that threw the exception and the detailed exception info for us to troubleshoot this issue.